# K8s NetworkPolicy behavior when `ports: {}`

Tags: kubernetes

The [K8s documentation on NetworkPolicy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.26/#networkpolicyingressrule-v1-networking-k8s-io) states that if the `spec.ingress.from.ports` array is not specified, traffic is allowed from any `port` for the matching `peers` array:

> List of ports which should be made accessible on the pods selected for this rule. Each item in this list is combined using a logical OR. **If this field is empty or missing, this rule matches all ports (traffic not restricted by port)**. If this field is present and contains at least one item, then this rule allows traffic only if the traffic matches at least one port in the list.

But what if one of the `port` items inside of `ports` is created like this?

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: empty-port-item-network-policy
  namespace: some-namespace
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: front
  ingress:
    - from:
      - podSelector: {}

      ports:
        - {}
```

When I `describe` this NetworkPolicy, I don't get enough information (ignore `PodSelector=none`):

```
Created on:   2023-01-02 18:58:32 +0200 IST
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
Spec:
  PodSelector:     app=front
  Allowing ingress traffic:
    To Port: <nil>/TCP
    From:
      PodSelector: <none>
  Not affecting egress traffic
  Policy Types: Ingress
```

What does `To Port: <nil>/TCP` mean here? Any port? all ports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing an empty array to the ports when using:

```
  ports:
    - {}
```

This means that no ports are allowed. Everything is blocked.

When omitting the ports entry, you would allow traffic to all ports.
kubectl describe output:

```
  Allowing ingress traffic:
    To Port: <any> (traffic allowed to all ports)
```

The yaml would be something like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: empty-port-item-network-policy
  namespace: some-namespace
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: front
  ingress:
    - from:
      - podSelector: {}
```

Comment: I'm actually not so sure this answer is correct, after seeing that `namespaceSelector: {}` actually selects ALL namespaces, even though the `kubectl describe commands` outputs: *"NamespaceSelector: <none>"*.

Comment: @zerohedge , that is the same thing, the `namespaceSelector: {}` is an empty map. To the same in your yaml, you can have the ports entry as: `ports: []` which is an empty array. What was configured earlier is an empty first element (nil).

Comment: So `ports: []` means any port, but `ports: {}` means first element array is `nil`?

Comment: yes and no :) :
`ports: []` --> empty array (means all ports)(same as ommitting)
`ports: {}` --> would not work, the apply command would fail because it expects an array not a map.
`- {}` --> nil entry (no ports are allowed)